# How to redirect to html page after login with facebook

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

good afternoon, 
@peter or @PeterSmith

I have been trying to use "login with Facebook" on my website for 15 days. I have been using the code published by Facebook, at the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/v2.2)

My problem with this code is that I want the customer after login with his Facebook (through the window that pop out) to be redirected to a specific page on my website, but what happens is that after the customer does login with your Facebook, the client is redirected to the same page that asks him to login.

I have already followed the steps that are explained in the link that I mentioned earlier. Could someone help me?

the code i am using is this:

```js
function statusChangeCallback(response) { // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
  console.log('statusChangeCallback');
  console.log(response); // The current login status of the person.
  if (response.status === 'connected') { // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
    testAPI();
  } else { // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
      'into this webpage.';
  }
}


function checkLoginState() { // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { // See the onlogin handler
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}


window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: '{xxxxxxx}',
    cookie: true, // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
    xfbml: true, // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
    version: '{api-version}' // Use this Graph API version for this call.
  });


  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) { // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
    statusChangeCallback(response); // Returns the login status.
  });
};


(function(d, s, id) { // Load the SDK asynchronously
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function testAPI() { // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
      'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
  });
}
```

```html
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>

<div id="status"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0&appId=505608310005112&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="" data-button-type="continue_with" data-layout="rounded" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

Comment: You are going to need to provide code that you use to handle this event. We are NOT going to just guess at how you are doing things without it.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. The code is this:

Comment: I don’t even see you _trying_ to redirect somewhere else here …?

Comment: If you have this code on _every_ page, it will call `FB.getLoginStatus`, and with that your `statusChangeCallback`, on each page load. You would need to differentiate here between and actual login by clicking the button, and an implicit login by just “recognizing” the user again on the following pages.

Comment: @CBroe,Thank you very much for your comment. I am not a expert on coding i am trying to sort out this problem the best way i know. Basically, i have a page called "MENU" with lots of options, and when you click on one of these options, you will be redirect to a page with only with a option called "Login" and here you can login with FB, only. Everything goes ok till the "Login with FB" is accepted, When the Login with the FB, is accepted, it should be redirected to a page called "Menu II", but it not happen, cose stay on the same page "LOGIN WITH FB". If you could help me i would appreciated

Comment: Try and replace the `testAPI();` call inside the condition that checks if the status is "connected", to `location.href = "{url for your menu 2 page}"`

Comment: Thank you once again i'll try it than i'll back to you!